# Deaf speechmarks?

Tags: style, technique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one present spoken dialogue as a secondary language to signed speech?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/how-does-one-present-spoken-dialogue-as-a-secondary-language-to-signed-speech)

I want to write a novel and I was thinking of including a deaf character. I want to know the best way to express what the deaf person is signing because I don't think using speechmarks would be appropriate.

Comment: I think this should be on writers.se, but I suggest using a different typeface (italics if you've nothing better).

Comment: Another alternative would be to use different speech demarcation symbols - put the signings <between characters like this, for example>.

Comment: Science fiction authors deal with unusual forms of communication (e.g. telepathy) all the time.  They usually handle it by using *italics*.

Answer (score 2):

You would simply treat this as you would any other foreign language. The fact that the language is communicated by signing rather than speaking is immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

We just addressed this [recently,](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/how-does-one-present-spoken-dialogue-as-a-secondary-language-to-signed-speech) and the excellent answer suggested was *guillemets*. « and »

Answer (score 0):

guillemets, as suggested by Lauren Ipsum, is a good option. Another one, that would appeal to me in reading it, would be to not use any speech marks:

"Do you like my use of language?" he questioned.

I wish you would sign more, she signed back.

The reason is that this sounds more silent to me - I read this, and get the silence and the occasional slap as the person signs back.

Of course, this would not always work, but it would make me think each time I read it, how this was being communicated.